# Using function.call with this argument for function arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, this

I have a simple example below which creates an Object constructor. There is an `add` method which attempts to iterate through the `arguments` collection by calling the `Array.prototype.forEach` method.

The technique works, but I’m having a problem with the `this` value.

I have resorted to the trick of assigning `this` to a real variable (`This`), an using the the real value in the inner function. This works, but I though it should be simpler.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call, I should be able to call this with an optional `thisArg` at the beginning. I have tried this in the `add2` method. This *doesn’t* work.

What is the correct way of including a new value for `this` argument in the `call` method?

```js
function Collection() {
  this.data=[];
}
Collection.prototype={
  constructor: Collection,
  add() {
    var This=this;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments,function(value) {
      This.data.push(value);
    });
  },
  add2() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this,arguments,function(value) {
      this.data.push(value);
    });
  },
}

var c=new Collection();
c.add('apple','banana');
alert(c.data)
```

Comment: Just use arrow functions instead, which inherit their `this` from the outer scope rather than gaining it from their calling context. Also consider using argument rest syntax rather than `arguments`.

Comment: Actually, I’m writing a polyfill which precludes arrow functions. I know they would make life easier.

Comment: If you can't use arrow functions, then `that = this` and then referring to `that` later is pretty much the only other way to do it. But if at all possible, write in the latest syntax possible and then use Babel to transpile it later - makes for fewer headaches like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` takes an optional parameter for `this` which it will use inside the callback. It should be a good option if you can't use arrow functions:

```js
function Collection() {
    this.data=[];
  }
  Collection.prototype={
    constructor: Collection,
   
    add2() {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments,function(value) {
        this.data.push(value);
      }, this); // <= pass this in to forEach
    },
  }
  
  var c=new Collection();
  c.add2('apple','banana');
  console.log(c.data)
```

Comment: I can’t accept the answer yet (I have to wait another 5 minutes for some reason), but thanks. Would you mind checking the information on this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Syntax to see whether I have misconstrued it? I’m sure that it suggests that the `this` argument should be first.

Comment: @Manngo, yes that's a little confusing. In the example above, `this` is being passed  into `forEach()` not `call()`. It's the last optional parameter listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I understand now. The argument list belongs to the `forEach` method, not the `call` method. Thanks again.